# Is this array initialization incorrect?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public byte[][,] Shapes = 
    {
        {
            {1,1}, 
            {1,1}
        }, 
        {
            {1}, 
            {1}, 
            {1}, 
            {1}
        },
        {
            {0,0,1},
            {1,1,1}
        }
    };
```

I get this error:
"Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead."

I could do this...

```
public class Shape
{
    public byte[][,] Shapes;

    public Shape()
    {
        Shapes = new byte[3][,];

        Shapes[0] = new byte[2, 2];
        Shapes[0][0, 0] = 1;
        Shapes[0][0, 1] = 1;
        Shapes[0][1, 0] = 1;
        Shapes[0][1, 1] = 1;

        Shapes[1] = new byte[1, 4];
        Shapes[1][0, 0] = 1;
        Shapes[1][0, 1] = 1;
        Shapes[1][0, 2] = 1;
        Shapes[1][0, 3] = 1;
    }
}
```

But that makes it very hard to add more shapes to my program.

Is my initializer wrong? And if I'm not allowed to do it this way, what's the easiest way to set it out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  public byte[][,] Shapes = new byte[3][,]
    {
        new byte[,] { {1,1}, {1,1} },
        new byte[,] { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} },
        new byte[,] { {0,0,1}, {1,1,1} }
    };
```

Comment: Note, of course, for anyone that might come across this and not already know, that for any additional items beyond these 3 rows, the 3 gets incremented.  I thought, when I first saw this, that maybe the 3 was for the number of items (available slots) in each array, starting at 0.  It's not.  It's for the number of rows, starting with 1.

Answer (score 8):

Array initializer syntax (`{ ... }`) can only be used to initialize a field or variable.
To make arrays inside the outer array, you need to use normal array creation syntax.

Add `new []` before the inner `{ ... }` to create an implicitly-typed array.

Since you're dealing with `byte`s and multi-dimensional arrays, you may need to explicitly specify some of the types, by writing `new byte[,] { ... }`.

Comment: Translation:  Basically the same as Cheeso's answer, minus the example, except for that sometimes you can ditch the type.